# Spring on jBoss 7.1 can not cast FactoryBean to Factory in xml application context

Tags: java, spring, jboss7.x

I have xml application context and next bean factory definition:

```
 <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="<unit name>" />
  <property name="jpaProperties">
    <props>
      <some properties>
    </props>
  </property>
</bean>    
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
  <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

So when I'm deploying it on the Tomcat 7.0.52 - it works: spring "cast" factory bean into factory well. But when I'm deploying it on jBoss 7.1.0, I'm getting the following exception:

```
Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-persistence.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean' to required type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' for property 'entityManagerFactory'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] to required type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] for property 'entityManagerFactory': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527) [spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
```

Are there any differences in work of Spring in Tomcat and jBoss?

Comment: Are you sure you have the same .war file?

Comment: Try one thing: if you have a `META-INF/persistence.xml` file change its name to something else. For example `jpapersistence.xml` and add the following to your `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`: `<property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/jpapersistence.xml"/>`

Answer (score 0):

The reason may be transactionManager of jboss-self.
I guess,when jboos startup,it could init transactionManager in context.

Answer (score 0):

I found that spring uses different classes to create entity manager on Tomcat and jBoss. But it happens only when i'm deploying my "persistence module" as ejb part. When i'm using it as jar file - it works well.